# Sending very big array/object in function call as parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, node.js, mongodb

I am writing a chat server in node.js. I have a array with all the user token and "socket object" for these user tokens.

Now when I want to send a msg I have to make a function call in this function call I have to get few things from mongodb, it might take some time so I am also sending a callback function in this function. In the callback function i am sending the chat msg to all the recipient user (through the socket which is in the array).

So my question is - is it ok to send very big arrays / objects in function call? Will it effect performance? If yes then is there any thumb of rule how we should handle these situations?

Comment: Can you please share some code.

Comment: It's ok since arrays and other objects are passed by reference. Passing large strings also seems to be fast, I assume they are not copied, since they are immutable anyway. (http://jsperf.com/passing-string-vs-object)